# Getting current hour and minute in datetime format in python

Tags: python, class, time, compare

I would like to get the current time in a specific format in python:

1. 'H:M' format
2. 'datetime.time' class

This is because I'm trying to compare the current time with another time in this exact format, I get from an excel file.

when I try the obvious:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> now = datetime.now()
>>> current_time = (now.hour, now.minute)
>>> current_time > other_time
```

('other time' is for example 'datetime.time(8, 30)')

I get:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.time' and 'tuple'
```

I tried all kinds of stuff and searched all over but couldn't find anything that works for me, it always comes down to unsupported instances like 'tuple' 'str' or else.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: so other_time is a datetime.time object?  why not convert it to a tuple just like you did with current_time before comparing them?

Comment: ... `current_time > (other_time.hour, other_time.minute)` should do it ...